# opencv: Time complexity to detect minimum rectangle

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, rectangles

I am starting to learn minimum rectangle detection with opencv. I need to calculate time complexity for that, but still confuse about these methods:

1. findContours().
2. minAreaRect()

Anyone can help me

1. how those methods work?
2. what is the time complexity for those methods?

any reference is appreciable

Answer (score 4):

`cv::findContours()` retrieves contours from the binary image using the algorithm ([link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0734189X85900167)):

> *Suzuki, S. and Abe, K., Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized
>   Binary Images by Border Following. CVGIP 30 1, pp 32-46 (1985)*

The basic concept of this algorithm consists of tracking the edges by considering a topological analysis. Therefore, the relationship between inner and outer edges is extracted. In practice, the algorithm discriminates between outer and inner borders and classifies them hierarchically, so a contour is considered to be "parent" to another contour if it surrounds the contour.

And on the other hand `cv::minAreaRect()` finds the oriented minimum bounding box enclosing a set of points. It is a type of bounding volume. It is sufficient to find the smallest enclosing box for the convex hull of the objects. For the convex polygon, a linear time algorithm for the minimum-area enclosing rectangle is known. It is based on the observation that a side of a minimum-area enclosing box must be collinear with a side of the convex polygon (see [[1](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=360919)]). It is possible to enumerate boxes of this kind in linear time with the approach called [rotating calipers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers).

Comment: Thanks @Kornel for the answer and references.. ok, I'm trying to read it first :)

Comment: Did you find anything about the time complexity of findContours? this should really be mentionned in the opencv docs, but I cant find it..